Código Pine script V5 no considera condición de precio para abrir nuevas órdenes
El siguiente código busca crear órdenes de compra y venta en la intersección de medias móviles simples de 1 y 6 períodos, pero que primero valide respectivamente si existe una posición abierta larga o corta según sea el caso. En cualquier escenario, he ingresado una instrucción para validar antes de crear una orden de venta si el precio de entrada de la posición larga es un 0,05% menor que el precio del cruce actual (para evitar que la cierre en pérdidas o en cero) y para validar las órdenes de compra si la entrada de la posición corta es un 0,05% mayor que el precio del nuevo cruce (para evitar que la cierre en pérdidas o en cero). Lo que busca la segunda condición es no crear nuevas órdenes que puedan cerrar la posición contraria en pérdidas, una vez que se cumpla la segunda condición debe seguir creando órdenes con base en la primera instrucción (cruce de medias móviles).
Pese a que he codificado instrucciones para que esto se realice, al momento no reconoce la segunda condición y crea las órdenes sin realizar la validación del precio.
Si alguien tiene alguna alternativa que pueda incorporar a la lógica u otro método para acercarme al resultado lo gradeceré mucho.
Un gran saludo.
Código:
strategy("MagicTrend - Prueba AB [2]", overlay=true, pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, initial_capital=100, default_qty_value=10, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.02, calc_on_order_fills=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, fill_orders_on_standard_ohlc=true)

// Variables para almacenar el estado de la posición y el precio de entrada

var bool inLongPosition = false
var bool inShortPosition = false
float entryPriceLong_ = strategy.position_avg_price
float entryPriceShort_ = strategy.position_avg_price

// Condiciones de cruce

longCondition_price = entryPriceLong_ * 100 / 99.8
shortCondition_price = entryPriceShort_ * 99.8 / 100
VP_LongCondition = strategy.position_avg_price > longCondition_price
VP_ShortCondition = strategy.position_avg_price < shortCondition_price 
longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 1), ta.sma(close, 6))
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 1), ta.sma(close, 6))


if (longCondition)
    if (VP_ShortCondition) 
        strategy.close("Sell")
        inShortPosition := false
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    inLongPosition := true    
    
    

if (shortCondition)
    if (VP_LongCondition) 
        strategy.close("Buy")
        inLongPosition := false
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
    inShortPosition := true
    

// Mantener actualizadas las variables

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    inLongPosition := strategy.position_size > 0
    inShortPosition := strategy.position_size < 0


// Mostrar señales de cruce

plotshape(series=longCondition, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0), style=shape.triangleup, textcolor=#ff0000, text="ca")
plotshape(series=shortCondition, location=location.abovebar, color=#6fff52, style=shape.triangledown, textcolor=#53e237, text="cd")


¿Cuál es la diferencia entre esta pregunta y esta otra?

Hola @padaleiana, es el mismo caso. El inicio opté por modificar una pregunta antgua (la que compartes), luego consideré que era mejor crear una pregunt nueva. Un saludo.

Hola. Para validar si existe una posición abierta, usa strategy.position_size

Gracias Gustavo, haré los ajustes y probaré. Ten un gran día.
